# Printing a TreeMap using a for loop in Java

Tags: java

I use the following code:

```
public void showTablet () {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Tablet> entry : tableMap.entrySet()) {     
        System.out.println(entry.toString());
    }
}
```

The result is :

```
MyBrand : A123=Brand: MyBrand, Model no.:A123, Price:3000.0
BrandTwo : T222=Brand: BrandTwo, Model no.:T222, Price:2500.0
```

My wanted result

```
Brand: MyBrand, Model no.:A123, Price:3000.0
Brand: BrandTwo, Model no.:T222, Price:2500.0
```

Why is the key also printed out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're printing a `Map.Entry`, which contains both the key and the value.

If you only want the value, you can use `Map.Entry`'s `getValue()` method:

```
System.out.println(entry.getValue()); // will call toString by default
```

That is assuming that `Tablet` has a properly overriden `toString` method, of course (which it seems to have, if I understand your output correctly).

Comment: Or just iterate through [`Map.values()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) and skip the entry set altogether.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to mess with the Entry.

```
for(Tablet tablet : tabletMap.values()) {
    System.out.println(tablet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of getting the key/value pairs...

```
public void showTablet () {
     for (Map.Entry<String, Tablet> entry : tableMap.keySet()) {     
        System.out.println("Key: " + entry + " Value: " + tableMap.get(entry));
    }
}
```